# Parse.com for a web client reload page when data changes

Tags: parse-platform

I am using Parse with Express-JS. What I would like to achieve is observe changes in the data and load a different page when a specific value changes. I believe I should be able to handle the changes with Cloud Code afterSave method, but how I achieve real time communication with the web client. Is that possible with Parse only or do I have to use other services like Pubnub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Parse JavaScript API has no support for push notifications or any kind of pub/sub framework.

Your simples option is to poll for changes, just make sure that the requests are far enough apart as to no overload your req/sec quota.